# C# - Is Comparing 2 floats an expensive operation?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Using Unity's update method, I want to know if comparing 2 floats is more or less expensive than simply setting a Unity slider value. For example:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (oldValue != _currentValue) // This being the comparison of 2 floats
        {
            _chargeBar.value = _currentValue;
        }
    }
```

vs

```
void Update()
    {          
        _chargeBar.value = _currentValue;          
    }
```

Let me explain what is going on. I have a Unity UI slider which I am updating the value. I am wanting to only update the value if my 2 floats are different. However I could just update the slider value every update if its less expensive compared to comparing 2 floats are a high precision. Either way one will have to be evaluated at the end of every frame. I would just like to know which would be better. Or an alternative approach. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just profiling it?

Comment: No I haven't. I don't currently know how to do that. But I will look in to it.

Comment: This is a performance issue you dont need to look into.

Comment: Use a `Stopwatch` and call `Update` thousands of time straight (with different oldValues and currentValues, and with same ones), then measure the time that passed before the first and the last call (of those thousands) to `Update()`. Change the parameters and change the number of iterations and try again. Measure different scenarios. 

That said: unless changing a slider is a **really** costly operation (like, it has side effects that might consume processing power), I doubt this has any serious performance impact on any application (either with the comparison, or without it)

Comment: As @Jcl mentioned, I think the real question you need to be asking is what the cost is of setting the chargeBar value. Does it invoke some kind of paint routine? That kind of stuff is going to be astronomically more expensive than comparing a couple of floats.

Comment: TL;DR: if changing the slider is just "setting a value" (no side effects), just don't make the comparison... if it has side effects, then do it.

Comment: What if the _delta_ between values is too small to affect the displayed value? This looks like optimization that you shouldn't be doing. Unity should be able to quickly determine whether the UI would be altered and do the right thing.

Comment: You've given me some good points to consider. To elaborate on the slider. When I set the value, it will have to update my GUI so a draw call will be made every time the value is set. So potentially every frame. I presume this will be more expensive operation as a result. Thanks Guys

Comment: @Stoward94 generally, most accelerated UIs are drawn every frame regardless of their values, so that's more likely an invalid point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison is fast, but if statements are not because processors are executing multiple commands at the same time in a pipeline. If there is a conditional jump like if statement the processor needs to start executing other branch before the branch direction is determined. If it is realized that the selected branch is the wrong one, all instructions in it needs to be flushed. After the flush the other branch is executed but this takes much more time than predicting the branch correctly in the first place.

On the other hand optimization is quite pointless, because the draw call is quite likely made anyways on every frame. This is because it is easy to just clear the whole frame with the background color and draw everything again. For sure the draw call needs to be made on every frame, if there are any transparency in the UI. In that case the transparent UI needs to be drawn as the last element on top of everything else.

Also it is quite likely that, if this optimization is actually useful, it is already implemented in the Unity's build in draw functions for the UI slider.